# Problema método focus()

Tags: extjs

Basado en un problema personal con `ExtJS` y en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591371/set-focus-on-extjs-textfield) lo planteo aquí también por si alguien más se encuentra con que el método `focus()` no pone el foco realmente cuando debería hacerlo, acorde a la documentación del framework.

Éste es el código de ejemplo ([se puede ver corriendo en este fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1u70&view/)):

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Panel Test',
            layout: 'vbox',
            margin: 15, padding: 5,
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            defaults: {
                 layout: 'fit'
             },
            items: [
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                    name: 'first',
                    id: 'first_name',
                    value: 'first_name',
                    allowBlank: false
                },
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                    name: 'last'
                },
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'Company',
                    name: 'company'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    anchor: '100%',
                    fieldLabel: 'From',
                    format: 'd/m/Y',
                    name: 'from_date',
                    itemId: 'from_date',
                    value: new Date(),
                    maxValue: new Date()  // limited to the current date or prior
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    anchor: '100%',
                    fieldLabel: 'To',
                    format: 'd/m/Y',
                    name: 'to_date',
                    itemId: 'to_date',
                    value: new Date()  // defaults to today
                }
            ],


            listeners: {
                afterrender: function() {
                    var me = this;
                    me.myFunc();
                }
            },

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            myFunc: function() {
            //alert("functionOne called");
            //here try to focus
            //Ext.getCmp('from_date').focus(); // <== descomentar esta linea
            Ext.getCmp('first_name').focus();   // <-- esto funciona bien
            Ext.getCmp('first_name').selectText(); // <-- esto tambien
        }


        });

    }
});
```

Quiero ponerle el foco a la fecha por defecto pero no puedo. He probado con el método `isFocusable()` y siempre me sale como `false`. Lo hago de este modo y no con la propiedad `selectOnFocus` porque el foco debe ponerse desde otra función.

Agradezco cualquier comentario que me ayude a solventarlo.